# Behaviors in Polymer ES6 class

Tags: polymer, ecmascript-6

How can I use behaviors in Polymer element build with ES6 class ? I was trying to use existing ES5 behavior with newly defiend ES6 element but I'm getting 'error TyperError: this.log is not a function' when I'm calling function defined in behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org">
  <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-element id="myElement" verbose></my-element>
</body>


<script>
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    // Behavior (ES5)
    var myBehaviors = myBehaviors || {};
    myBehaviors.VerboseBehavior = {
      properties: {
        verbose: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }
      },
      log: function(msg) {
        if (!this.verbose) {
          return;
        }
        if (this.id) {
          console.log(this.localName + ' (#' + this.id + '): ' + msg);
        } else {
          console.log(this.localName + ': ' + msg);
        }
      }
    };

    // Element (ES6)
    class myElement {
      beforeRegister() {
        this.is = 'my-element';

        this.behaviors = [
          myBehaviors.VerboseBehavior
        ];

        this.properties = {
          hello: {
            type: String,
            value: 'world'
          }
        };
      }

      ready() {
        this.log('ready'); // error TypeError: this.log is not a function
      }

      attached() {
        this.say();
      }

      say() {
        console.log(this.hello);
      }
    };

    Polymer(myElement);
  })();
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the behaviors with a getter.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    let SkeletonPolymerBehavior = {
        // Behavior definition
    };

    class SkeletonPolymer {

        // Define behaviors with a getter
        get behaviors() {
            return [SkeletonPolymerBehavior];
        }

        // Element setup goes here instead of created() callback
        beforeRegister() {}

        // Define other lifecycle methods as you need
        registered() {}
        created() {}
        ready() {}
        factoryImpl() {}
        attached() {}
        detached() {}
        attributChanged(){}
    }
    Polymer(SkeletonPolymer);
)();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the answer given by leodido will not work if you use extended behaviors. Extended behaviors in Polymer are arrays of behaviors themselves. I don't know what's going on exactly but apparently Polymer is parsing the protoype of your class and flattening the behavior array, writing the flattened version back to your prototype. The fixed getter function will ignore the flattened version and always return the deep array. That will not do. So you have two options.
You can flatten the array yourself:

```
get behaviors() {
    return [
        MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior
    ].reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);});
}
```

However, since Polymer may call get behaviors a lot (it does in my case), this will introduce a minor performance penalty. The alternative is letting it set the behaviors:

```
let SkeletonPolymerBehavior = [MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior];
class SkeletonPolymer {
    get behaviors( ) {return SkeletonPolymerBehavior;}
    set behaviors(b) {SkeletonPolymerBehavior = b;}
    ...
}
```

Finally you can flatten the array right away:

```
let SkeletonPolymerBehavior = [
    MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior
].reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);});
class SkeletonPolymer {
    get behaviors( ) {return SkeletonPolymerBehavior;}
    ...
}
```

Note that my flatten function is *not* safe! It worked in my case, but it will fail when extending extended behaviors and possibly in other cases. You definitely need something more sophisticated there. If you don't want to bother (and I see no compelling reason to) you should definitely go with the second version, letting Polymer set the behaviors.

Final note: I tried abstracting that away into an es2015 Behaviors mixin. However, Polymer's prototype magic does not catch stuff inherited from base classes and the getters and setters defined there are never called.

However, it is possible to mess with the prototype the es5 way. This utility function will ease the addition of extended behaviors:

```
function addBehaviors(clas, ...behaviors) {
    let bhv = behaviors;
    Object.defineProperty(clas.prototype, "behaviors", {
        get:function( ) {return bhv;},
        set:function(b) {return bhv = b;}
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
class SkeletonPolymer {...}
addBehaviors(SkeletonPolymer, MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior);
```